# Some questions compiling linux kernel with make-kpkg

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling, linux-kernel, make

I'm doing my first steps compiling the linux kernel and adding a new system call. I've managed to do it, but I still have some questions.

For this task, I has set up a Virtual Machine guesting debian 7 64 bits. I am following a tutorial found in Internet of how to do this (http://arvindsraj.wordpress.com/2012/10/05/adding-hello-world-system-call-to-linux/)
And as documentation, overall, a manual of [how to create a custom linux kernel in Debian GNU/Linux](http://users.wowway.com/~zlinuxman/Kernel.htm) and the manual page for make-kpkg.

So far, I am using the next script to compile:

```
#!/bin/sh
make-kpkg clean
INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 CONCURRENCY_LEVEL=2 time make-kpkg --initrd --append-to-version=-$1 kernel_image
```

And, well, I have the following questions:

1. Right now, I'm defining kernel_image only as target. Should I include also kernel_headers? when should I compile and install the kernel_headers? what are they for?
2. If I use as target: binary_arch, is exactly the same than using kernel_image and kernel_headers?
3. I put INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 because I read that it compiles it faster and the output is much smaller. I know it reduces the number of modules being compiled. how much is this reduction? Should I use this flag for a final compilation for a final use of the kernel in my computer??

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'd recommend looking at the Debian Kernel Handbook instead. It seems kernel-package is no longer supported; its maintainer is not active. The methods described in that book is what the Debian kernel team current recommends.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Thank you, but I'm following this method and It works for me. I just want to respond the questions above.

Comment: You're better off using a supported method. I use to use kernel-package too, but be aware that that it will probably be less and less used by others. This package has not been updated by the maintainer since Tue, 20 Jul 2010 (12.036). It has been NMUed 3 times since then to deal with various issues by the kernel maintainers, but I suspect its usage will continue to fall. If you want an answer you are probably better off asking somewhere like the debian-user mailing list. The debian kernel mailing list might also be an option. See also https://wiki.debian.org/DebianKernel

Comment: As for 1, the kernel headers are used for compiling third party kernel modules. So install the kernel headers if you want to do that.

Comment: Ok, @FaheemMitha Thank you very much for your information, and I think, for now, that answer is enough for me.

Comment: @Touchy notes "@FaheemMitha, the most recent version of the Debian Kernel Handbook still includes a suggestion for compiling kernels with build-essential."